# Adding commas when echoing an array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I made a shoutbox yesterday and now I'm trying to make a page where site admins can delete certain posts.  This is my code currently:

```
<form method="post">
<?PHP
include("config.php");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC");
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        $id = addslashes($info['id']);
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$id\" name=\"delete[]\"><b>" .$info['name']. ": </b>" .$info['shout']."<br>";
    }
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
foreach($_POST['delete'] as $item){

mysql_query("DELETE * FROM shoutbox WHERE id = ".$item." ");
        echo "$item";

    }
}

?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

now the problem is, in the query when it says `("id = ".$item.")` it pulls all the id's properly but there is no comma between them so say I chose id's 5, 4 and 2 it plugs in 542 and that's not even an existing id.  How can I make it so commas show up so it deletes the proper comments?

Comment: Send the proper data in your post

Comment: Why the hell are you calling `$id = addslashes($info['id']);` to generate output for HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with ID created by joining other IDs, but with your `DELETE` query - there should be no `*` between `DELETE` and `FROM` keywords. You can see `542` because you are echoing each ID in a loop, without any new line / space / coma after the query.

Before executing any query, you should make sure that data concatenated into it is safe and expected. For numeric ID you can use `intval()` to have only numeric inputs:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM shoutbox WHERE id = ". intval($item));
```

Please also note, that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, please develop new code with `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<form method="post">
<?PHP
include("config.php");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $id = addslashes($info['id']);
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$id\" name=\"delete[]\"><b>" .$info['name']. ": </b>" .$info['shout']."<br>";
}//END WHILE LOOP
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $idList =   "'" . mysql_real_escape_string(implode("','", $_POST['delete'])) . "'";
    mysql_query("DELETE * FROM shoutbox WHERE id IN (" . $idList . ") ");
    echo $idList;
}//END IF

?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Escaping fail! This script is as vulnerable as the original script. There MUST be at least one call to `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: This is not my code (it is tweaked). I am using the code from the asker. You comment is rude.

Comment: @Sven How is the script vulnerable if the only inputs are checkboxes? There are no text inputs where they can enter queries

Comment: I added it anyway. Just ignore people like him who look for any reason do down vote or question everyone.

Comment: @Mic1780 you are being downwoted not for `any reasont`, but very specific - posting bad code without any any explanation. Now after your edit it is even worse, hence additional -1 from me.

Comment: An attacker does not need to send you checkboxes, they can send anything - just think the attacker uses firebug and manipulates the HTML. You cannot prevent this, you must assume that your variables contain ANYTHING. Deal with it - validate it, escape it, or reject it.